# System.in is closed abnormally

Tags: java, stream, java.util.scanner, inputstream

I want to use `Scanner` to read from console. I create a new object, initialize it and when the main thread's works are done, I call a function named `maintenance ()`. Then I instantiate a new `Scanner`:

```
private void maintenance ()
{
    Scanner in = new Scanner(System.in);
    while (in.hasNext())
    {
        String choice = in.next().toLowerCase();
        ...
```

Well, `in.hasNext()` returns false intead of blocking main Thread. When I debug `Scanner` class `next()`method:

```
public boolean hasNext() {
    ensureOpen();
    saveState();
    while (!sourceClosed) {
        if (hasTokenInBuffer())
            return revertState(true);
        readInput();
    }
    boolean result = hasTokenInBuffer();
    return revertState(result);
}
```

I see that `sourceClosed` value is `true`. Well I'm pretty sure that I never used `System.in` stream anywhere else, nor closed it. The stream seems to be closed in an unusual manner. I tried to create `Scanner` in `main()` method before doing everything else, but the problem persists.

I debugged again, and added `System.in` to watch list, and saw that it has following properties:

```
System.in = BufferedInputStream@1086
buf = {byte[8192]@1087} //All 0 values
count = 0
pos = 0
markpos = -1
marklimit = 0
in = {FileInputStream@1088} //Which is another class
```

Then I also added

```
System.out.println(System.in.read());
```

It prints -1, means stream is closed.
This is really unusual. Can someone help me about probable solutions?

Comment: Somewhere in your code, someone called System.setIn(), and passed a BufferedInputStream over a FileInputStream. Which kind of app is that?

Comment: @JBNizet This is main class and main method. Nothing happens before using System.in. I use Gradle as build system. Can Gradle cause such problems? Anyway I'm writing some kinda framework and the only participant is me

Comment: How do you run your app? From gradle, or just by executing your main class?

Comment: @JBNizet I use Gradle run task

Comment: That's most probably the reason. Try just running your main class, out of gradle.

Comment: @JBNizet It works without Gradle.But I need a build system ofcourse (Preferably Gradle)

Comment: A build system is used to build. Running your app shouldn't need a build system.